# Draw figure, combining curves and lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Consider the following picture:

[image: chess-pawn]

I would like to draw this picture using LaTeX (preferably PSTricks but Ti*k*Z is also fine).

The space between the two curves should be completely yellow.

P.S. I know that this is a "please do it for me" question (sorry for that!) but I really don't know how to draw this at all.

Comment: @CroCo Did you even read the question?  He even explains himself.

Comment: @CroCo And the OP is being picky about application and colouring. If you have no clue how to do it why would you care whether it is `pstricks`, MetaPost or `picture`?

Comment: @HenriMenke So if new users write that 'explanation', you won't vote to close their questions as duplicates of 'what packages are there ...?'

Comment: @cfr Sometimes you just get stuck and don't know where to start, see [this question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158585).  I agree that the phrasing could be improved though.

Comment: @HenriMenke So why do you close all the newbies' questions? Only high rep users are allowed to get stuck? I think there is something to be said for being more tolerant of do-it-for-mes from new users than established users. But, apparently, you think the right to not have a clue has to be earned by accumulating points by having a clue what to do, which seems like catch-22 for beginners.

Comment: @cfr Because newbies have not contributed anything.  Svend has 331 answers.

Comment: @HenriMenke And they never will if you have your way.

Comment: @HenriMenke and yet in this post [Wind Turbine drive train model in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390768/wind-turbine-drive-train-model-in-tikz), you've written this comment *Member for 5 years and no MWE? -1*. I consider this as a double standard.

Comment: @CroCo Go to account »Newest Answers (0)«...

Comment: @cfr, when some people like posts, they will search for any excuses to not downvote or close a post, something like *He even explains himself.* :)

Comment: @HenriMenke, why do I have to go there? Also, in your first comment, how did you know that I haven't read the question? Accusing me not read the question is some sort of searching for excuses. No need for this kind of double standard. Experienced users should provide some MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this comes somewhat close.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3]
  \draw[double=yellow,double distance=2pt,line join=round,looseness=3]
  (0,0)
  -- (1,0)
  to[out=70,in=-10,looseness=1] (.5,.5)
  to[out=10,in=-10] (.25,.75)
  to[out=10,in=0] (0,1)
  to[out=180,in=170] (-.25,.75)
  to[out=190,in=170] (-.5,.5)
  to[out=190,in=120,looseness=1] (-1,0)
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg It's not `pstricks` though.  I don't know how to draw a connected `\ncarc` to get the rounded corners.  Maybe you find a way to convert it.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, with pstricks

I feel there ought to be (surely) an easier way of continuing an arc from the previous point, but I couldn't find it.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\def\lstxy{!CP \csname tx@UserCoor\endcsname}
\newcommand\psrarcn[4][]{%
  \psarcn[#1](\lstxy exch #3 cos #2 mul sub exch #3 sin #2 mul sub){#2}{#3}{#4}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-8,-1)(8,20)
\foreach \lnwd/\lncl in {30pt/black, 25pt/yellow}{
  \pscustom[linewidth=\lnwd,linecolor=\lncl,linejoin=1]{
    \psline(0,0)(!220 cos 5 mul 220 cos 2 mul add 0)
    \psrarcn{5}{220}{90}
    \psrarcn{3}{270}{90}
    \psrarcn{2}{225}{-45}
    \psrarcn{3}{90}{-90}
    \psrarcn{5}{90}{-40}
    \psline(\lstxy)(0,0)
}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\fig#1#2{\pscustom[arrows=c-c,linewidth=#1,linecolor=#2,linejoin=1]{%
    \psline(-4.9,0)(4.9,0)
    \psarc(0,1){5}{-10}{73}
    \psarc(0,7.5){2.15}{-50}{70}
    \psarc(0,11){1.6}{-60}{240}
    \psarc(0,7.5){2.15}{110}{230}
    \psarc(0,1){5}{107}{190}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1)(6,13)
\fig{6mm}{black}
\fig{5mm}{yellow}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant. If I compile the code (using `xelatex`), a piece of the figure is missing at the bottom left corner.

Comment: Oh, the `arrows=c-c` was missing in `\pscustom`