# How to draw pictures of surfaces in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, draw

So i've recently started to practise drawing (orientable) surfaces using TikZ wich resulted in my first figure that looks like this:

[image]

Which i am quite proud of, even though it might not be much. However, a few weeks ago i accidentally stumpled upon a few illustrations like this one in partcular

[image: source: http://brickisland.net/cs177/?p=144]

(source in picture description added)

and i would really love to know whether this was (possibly) done in TikZ or LaTeX in general and if you guys could give me a few hints on how to learn to create such figures by myself. I know that the TikZ-Manual is a good start but i feel a bit lost and even though i spent almost dozens of hours learning how to draw curved lines in TikZ i only managed to do my first figure mainly by accident to be honest.

**To sum it up:** Where would be a good start for me to learn how to draw such figures or what exactly would help me start learning this? For example: there are many different ways to draw curved lines. Which approach would help me the most if i wanted to recreate the 2nd figure basically? I am also quite curious on how to manage to do the vertical lines on the surface.

Any advise is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

**PS:** I am by no means looking for someone to recreate the shown figure. I am mainly interested in learning the skills to recreate such things by my own in the future.

Comment: @marmot i am of course willing to use everything that helps me creating such figures. I've never heard of asymptote before. Please excuse my lack of knowledge regarding the different tools. I am quite new to this stuff.

Comment: I think i actually came across a few asymptote graphics if i recall correctly. However, i am in fact really looking to get things done in tikz due to its unique "vector"-look. Maybe that makes my intentions a bit clearer. The 2nd figure just looks so smooth!

Comment: that looks really cool indeed! But for now, i am really mostly trying to make my figures like more like the 2nd figure in my opening question. But i am definitely willing to learn asymptote if that's the way to go to create such figures (preferably in the same style as the 2nd figure)

Comment: This link can be a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158585/draw-3d-intersecting-surfaces

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here we go then. Of course, there is some considerable room for improvement. Why does it look like fake 3D? Well, because it *is* fake 3D. You'd be better off with asymptote and/or if you find someone with a lot of skill and patience who is willing to help you. ;-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,fadings} % 
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3.14]

% restore these if you want to see where the axes point
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
% \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\begin{scope}[xshift=2mm,rotate=10]
\tikzfading[name=fade right,
            left color=transparent!60,
            right color=transparent!00] ;
\fill[gray!80, blur shadow={shadow blur
steps=10,shadow xshift=0pt,shadow yshift=0pt,shadow scale=1.15}]  plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=-90:270]
({1.2*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{1});
\filldraw[white,path fading=fade right,overlay] (-1.5,-1.3,1) --  (1.5,-1.3,1) -- 
(1.5,1.3,1) -- (-1.5,1.3,1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\draw[name path=back] plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=90:270]
({1.2*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*\x)});
\draw[name path=front] plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=-90:90]
({1.2*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*\x)}); 
\coordinate (front1) at ({1.2*cos(-45)},{sin(-45)},{1.6-0.4*cos(-2*45)});
\coordinate (front2) at ({1.2*cos(45)},{sin(45)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*45)});
\coordinate (front3) at ({1.2*cos(0)},{sin(0)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*0)});
\draw[name path=top,opacity=0.3] plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=-90:90]
(0,{sin(\x)},{1.8-0.2*cos(2*\x)});
\coordinate (top1) at (0,{sin(0)},{1.8-0.2*cos(2*0)});
\path[name intersections={of=top and back, by={tb}}];
\draw[name path=top front,opacity=0.3] (front1)  to[out=-10,in=-150] (front2);
\draw[name path=top front,opacity=0.3] (front3)  to[out=100,in=-20] (top1)
to[out=160,in=20] (tb);


%
\fill[blue,opacity=0.2] plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=-90:90]
(0,{sin(\x)},{1.8-0.2*cos(2*\x)}) --
plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=90:-90]
({1.2*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*\x)});

\fill[blue,opacity=0.2] plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=-90:90]
(0,{sin(\x)},{1.8-0.2*cos(2*\x)}) --
plot[variable=\x,samples=180,domain=90:270]
({1.2*cos(\x)},{sin(\x)},{1.6-0.4*cos(2*\x)});


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Added grid lines and made the shadow blurry.

Comment: this is beautifully done! i will patiently try to learn the general approach you've chosen with the code you provided. thanks a lot for the input! I can't wait to get my hands on it. :-)