# Add angles to 3d drone

Tags: tikz-3dplot

How can I add Euler angles and XYZ angles to the code like the picture?[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x = ( 20:-2cm), y = (-30: 2cm), z = ( 80: 1.6cm),
  > = Triangle]
\draw coordinate (O) (0,0,-.05) ellipse [radius=.2];

\foreach \xy/\yx in {x/y, y/x} {
  \fill[white] (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx = -.05) -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx=-.05)
            -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx =  .05) -- (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx= .05) -- cycle;
  \foreach \lmr in {-.05, 0, .05}
    \draw[gray] (xyz cs: \xy=-1, \yx = \lmr) -- (xyz cs: \xy=1, \yx=\lmr);
  \draw[fill=white, radius=.15] (xyz cs: \xy = -1) ellipse[]
                                (xyz cs: \xy =  1) ellipse[];
}
\draw[fill=white] (O) ellipse [radius=.2];

\foreach \xyz/\Label/\Ang in {% \Ang needs to start with a ,
  x/left/ {, longitude = 70},
  y/right/{, longitude =-20},
  z/above/{, longitude = 70, latitude=70}%
} {
  \draw[->, densely dashed, red] (0, 0, 0) -- ++(xyz cs: \xyz= 1.5)
    coordinate (ax-\xyz) node[\Label] {$\xyz$};
  \draw[blue, ->]
     (0, 0, 0) -- (xyz spherical cs: radius = 1.5,/tikz/style/.expanded=\Ang)
      coordinate (ax-\xyz') node[\Label] {$\xyz$};
}

\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  (0, 1) arc[start angle=90, delta angle=20, radius=1]
  node[midway, below right] {$\varphi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The added angles in your picture seem to be inconsistent. From psi and theta, I would assume, that you are using Tait-Bryan angles in the z-y-x sequence. In that case, there is an axis for the rotation by phi missing. Is that assumption correct, or do you actually what to draw Euler angles (like z-x-z) as well as Tait-Bryan angles? And do you also what to add the XYZ coordinate system?

Comment: @steffen-sk Actually, I want to show Euler angles, but I don't know how. Maybe the coordinates are incorrect. however, I am not able to do it.

Comment: In which sequence would you like to rotate around the axes? Your picture looks to me like rotating around the z- then the y- and finally the x-axis. Proper Euler angles would have sequence of axis of rotation like z-x-z, z-y-z, x-z-x or similar. Or don't you have a preference regarding the sequence?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the `tikz-3dplot` package. Within the package, there is already a coordinate transformation defined using Euler angles. You can find a similar question with some helpful answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118069/how-to-draw-an-euler-angle-rotation-sequence-with-tikz). Basically, you can define a main coordinate system of which you can set the orientation with two angles (e.g. `\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{115}`). Then, this coordinate system can be rotated via the command `\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{<angle1>}{<angle2>}{<angle3>}`. Within the package, this command is implemented to perform a rotation of the coordinate system using the Euler angles in the sequence z-y-z.

To get another sequence, one can redefine the transformation command as already discussed in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124234/283727) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392845/283727) to the [before mentioned question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118069/how-to-draw-an-euler-angle-rotation-sequence-with-tikz). This way, you can add ultimately all possible sequences and switch between them. In the code below, I used the z-y-x sequence (which are called Tait-Bryan or Cardan angles (see [Wikipedia for Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles))), since it is closest to the given picture and also the most common for Tait-Byran angles and also a z-x-z sequence as the most common classic Euler angles.

You can then either draw in the main or the rotated coordinate system. This way, it is easy to add any 3D drawing e.g. your drone and also the arcs to mark the angles. The `tikz-3dplot` package includes a `\tdplotdrawarc[coordinates_frame,->,colo]{origin}{radius}{start angle}{end angle}{node info}{label}` command but I found it to be more intuitiv to just draw the arc manually on the planes of the rotated coordinate systems with the option `canvas is xy plane at z=0` you've already used.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}
%\usetikzlibrary{3d, arrows.meta, calc, quotes}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

% Define new arc command
% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66220
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){%
    \draw [#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)}, {#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5)%
}
 
% Redefine the rotation sequence for the tikz3d-plot to Euler-Angles:
% z-x-z with alpha-beta-gamma (psi-theta-phi)
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118069/98906
\newcommand{\tdseteulerzxz}{%
    \renewcommand{\tdplotcalctransformrotmain}{%
        %
        % Determine the sin and cos of the specified angle in degrees
        % \tdplotsinandcos{sin}{cos}{theta}
        % - #1: Returns sin(#3)
        % - #2: Returns cos(#3)
        % - #3: User-specified angle theta
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sinalpha}{\cosalpha}{\tdplotalpha} 
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sinbeta}{\cosbeta}{\tdplotbeta}
        \tdplotsinandcos{\singamma}{\cosgamma}{\tdplotgamma}
        %
        % Define trigonometric abbreviations
        %
        \tdplotmult{\sasb}{\sinalpha}{\sinbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\sacb}{\sinalpha}{\cosbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\sacbsg}{\sacb}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sacbcg}{\sacb}{\cosgamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sasg}{\sinalpha}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sacg}{\sinalpha}{\cosgamma}
        %
        \tdplotmult{\sbsg}{\sinbeta}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sbcg}{\sinbeta}{\cosgamma}
        %
        \tdplotmult{\casb}{\cosalpha}{\sinbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\cacb}{\cosalpha}{\cosbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\cacbsg}{\cacb}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\cacbcg}{\cacb}{\cosgamma}
        \tdplotmult{\casg}{\cosalpha}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\cacg}{\cosalpha}{\cosgamma}
        %
        % Define the entries for the rotation matrix from the B-System to the I-System
        % This is A_IB = (A_BI)^T
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\raaeul}{+\cacg - \sacbsg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rabeul}{-\casg - \sacbcg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\raceul}{+\sasb}
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbaeul}{+\sacg + \cacbsg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbbeul}{-\sasg + \cacbcg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbceul}{-\casb}
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcaeul}{+\sbsg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcbeul}{+\sbcg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcceul}{+\cosbeta}
        %
    }
}
 
% Redefine the rotation sequence for the tikz3d-plot to Cardan-Angles:
% z-y-x with alpha-beta-gamma
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118069/98906
\newcommand{\tdsetcardanzyx}{%
    \renewcommand{\tdplotcalctransformrotmain}{%
        %
        % Determine the sin and cos of the specified angle in degrees
        % \tdplotsinandcos{sin}{cos}{theta}
        % - #1: Returns sin(#3)
        % - #2: Returns cos(#3)
        % - #3: User-specified angle theta
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sinalpha}{\cosalpha}{\tdplotalpha} 
        \tdplotsinandcos{\sinbeta}{\cosbeta}{\tdplotbeta}
        \tdplotsinandcos{\singamma}{\cosgamma}{\tdplotgamma}
        %
        % Define trigonometric abbreviations
        %
        \tdplotmult{\sasb}{\sinalpha}{\sinbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\sasbsg}{\sasb}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sasbcg}{\sasb}{\cosgamma}
        %
        \tdplotmult{\sacb}{\sinalpha}{\cosbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\sasg}{\sinalpha}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\sacg}{\sinalpha}{\cosgamma}
        %
        \tdplotmult{\casb}{\cosalpha}{\sinbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\casbsg}{\casb}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\casbcg}{\casb}{\cosgamma}
        %
        \tdplotmult{\cacb}{\cosalpha}{\cosbeta}
        \tdplotmult{\casg}{\cosalpha}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\cacg}{\cosalpha}{\cosgamma}
        \tdplotmult{\cbsg}{\cosbeta}{\singamma}
        \tdplotmult{\cbcg}{\cosbeta}{\cosgamma}
        %
        % Define the entries for the rotation matrix from the B-System to the I-System
        % This is A_IB = (A_BI)^T
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\raaeul}{+\cacb}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rabeul}{+\casbsg - \sacg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\raceul}{+\sasg+\casbcg}
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbaeul}{+\sacb}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbbeul}{+\cacg + \sasbsg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbceul}{\sasbcg-\casg}
        %
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcaeul}{-\sinbeta}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcbeul}{+\cbsg}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcceul}{+\cbcg}
        %
    }
}
 
% Plot display orientation
\tdplotsetmaincoords{50}{115}

\begin{document}


% z-y-x Tait-Bryan angles
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords,> = Triangle]
    % change ratation to z-y-x Tait-Bryan / Cardan angles
    \tdsetcardanzyx
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angpsi}{-20}  % or alpha
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angtheta}{-10}    % or beta
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angphi}{-5}   % or gamma

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2} % unit length radius      
    
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);     
    
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{\angphi}    
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=1.2]
        \draw coordinate (O) (0,0,-.05) ellipse [radius=.2];
        \foreach \xy/\yx in {x/y, y/x} {
          \fill[white] (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx = -.05) -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx=-.05)
                    -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx =  .05) -- (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx= .05) -- cycle;
          \foreach \lmr in {-.05, 0, .05}
            \draw[gray] (xyz cs: \xy=-1, \yx = \lmr) -- (xyz cs: \xy=1, \yx=\lmr);
          \draw[fill=white, radius=.15] (xyz cs: \xy = -1) ellipse[]
                                        (xyz cs: \xy =  1) ellipse[];
        }
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0,0) ellipse [radius=.2];
        
    \end{scope}     
    
    
    % original coordinate system
    \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right,z/above}
        \draw[->,blue] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz$};
    
    % angle of first rotation around z-axis
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:\angpsi:1.5);
    \node at ({1.7*cos(\angpsi/2)},{1.7*sin(\angpsi/2)},0){$\psi$};
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90+\angpsi:1.5);
    \node at ({-1.7*sin(\angpsi/2)},{1.7*cos(\angpsi/2)},0){$\psi$};    
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{0}{0}
    
    % new coordinate system
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right}
            \draw[->,green] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz'$};
        
        % angle of second rotation around new y-axis
        \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:-\angtheta:1.5);
        \node at ({1.7*cos(\angtheta/2)},0,{-1.7*sin(\angtheta/2)}){$\theta$};
        \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90-\angtheta:1.5);
        \node at ({1.7*sin(\angtheta/2)},0,{1.7*cos(\angtheta/2)}){$\theta$};
    \end{scope} 
    
        
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{0}  
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {z/above}
            \draw[->,magenta] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz''$};
        
        % angle of third rotation around new x-axis
        \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:\angphi:1.5);
        \node at (0,{1.7*cos(\angphi/2)},{1.7*sin(\angphi/2)}){$\varphi$};
        \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90+\angphi:1.5);
        \node at (0,{-1.7*sin(\angphi/2)},{1.7*cos(\angphi/2)}){$\varphi$};
    \end{scope}     
    
    % rotated coordinate system
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{\angphi}    
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right,z/above}
            \draw[->,densely dashed,red] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\tilde\xyz$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

% z-x-z Euler angles
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords,> = Triangle]
    % change ratation to z-y-x Tait-Bryan / Cardan angles
    \tdseteulerzxz
    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angpsi}{-10}  % or alpha
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angtheta}{-20}    % or beta
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angphi}{-10}  % or gamma

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2} % unit length radius      
    
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);     
    
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{\angphi}    
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,scale=1.2]
        \draw coordinate (O) (0,0,-.05) ellipse [radius=.2];
        \foreach \xy/\yx in {x/y, y/x} {
          \fill[white] (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx = -.05) -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx=-.05)
                    -- (xyz cs: \xy =  1, \yx =  .05) -- (xyz cs: \xy = -1, \yx= .05) -- cycle;
          \foreach \lmr in {-.05, 0, .05}
            \draw[gray] (xyz cs: \xy=-1, \yx = \lmr) -- (xyz cs: \xy=1, \yx=\lmr);
          \draw[fill=white, radius=.15] (xyz cs: \xy = -1) ellipse[]
                                        (xyz cs: \xy =  1) ellipse[];
        }
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0,0) ellipse [radius=.2];
        
    \end{scope}     
    
    
    % original coordinate system
    \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right,z/above}
        \draw[->,blue] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz$};
    
    % angle of first rotation around z-axis
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:\angpsi:1.5);
    \node at ({1.7*cos(\angpsi/2)},{1.7*sin(\angpsi/2)},0){$\psi$};
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90+\angpsi:1.5);
    \node at ({-1.7*sin(\angpsi/2)},{1.7*cos(\angpsi/2)},0){$\psi$};    
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{0}{0}
    
    % new coordinate system
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right}
            \draw[->,green] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz'$};
        
        % angle of second rotation around new x-axis
        \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:\angtheta:1.5);
        \node at (0,{1.7*cos(\angtheta/2)},{1.7*sin(\angtheta/2)}){$\theta$};
        \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90+\angtheta:1.5);
        \node at (0,{-1.7*sin(\angtheta/2)},{1.7*cos(\angtheta/2)}){$\theta$};
    \end{scope} 
    
        
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{0}  
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {y/right}
            \draw[->,magenta] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\xyz''$};
        
        % angle of third rotation around new z-axis
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (1.5,0) arc (0:\angphi:1.5);
        \node at ({1.7*cos(\angphi/2)},{1.7*sin(\angphi/2)},0){$\varphi$};
        \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,->] (0,1.5) arc (90:90+\angphi:1.5);
        \node at ({-1.7*sin(\angphi/2)},{1.7*cos(\angphi/2)},0){$\varphi$};
    \end{scope}     
    
    % rotated coordinate system
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\angpsi}{\angtheta}{\angphi}    
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords]
        \foreach \xyz/\Label in {x/left,y/right,z/above}
            \draw[->,densely dashed,red] (O) -- (xyz cs: \xyz=\r) node[\Label]{$\tilde\xyz$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Results:

Tait-Bryann z-y-x
[image: Tait-Bryan_zyx]
Euler z-x-z
[image: Euler_zxz]