# Indicating axis rotation with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I use `pgfplots` to render the mesh of a truncated cone in a 3D coordinate system like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
            view={15}{30},
            axis lines=center, 
            ticks = none,
            scaled ticks=false,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,  
            enlarge y limits=0.85,
            enlarge z limits=0.55,
            axis on top=true,
            x axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            y axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            z axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.4, 0.73)},anchor=north},
            xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$-z$}, zlabel={$y$}
            ]           
\addplot3[patch, opacity=0.7, patch table={indices.txt}] file {points.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current result:

[image: Truncated Cone]

I would also like to include an indication of the axis rotation similar to this thread: [Circular arrow in 3D to indicate a unit axis rotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118055/circular-arrow-in-3d-to-indicate-a-unit-axis-rotation)

[image: Rotations]

Is that possible with pgfplots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a MWE you could work with :

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            view={15}{30},
            axis lines=center, 
            ticks = none,
            scaled ticks=false,
            axis equal,
            enlarge x limits=0.25,  
            enlarge y limits=0.85,
            enlarge z limits=0.55,
            axis on top=true,
            x axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            y axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            z axis line style={opacity=0.5},
            y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.4, 0.73)},anchor=north},
            xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$-z$}, zlabel={$y$}]
  \addplot3[patch, opacity=0.7, patch table={indices.txt}] file {points.txt};
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=100]
    \draw [->] (30,0,0) arc (0:-350:30);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=100]
    \draw [->] (30,0,0) arc (0:-350:30);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=100]
    \draw [->] (30,0,0) arc (0:-350:30);
  \end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Looks great, thank you very much! I will see how I can make use of this!

Comment: Thank you for the good description. Would it be possible to get your data set once? I would like to create this plot from MATLAB data but I do not know exactly what data I need for this. Thank you very much!
Best regards

Comment: @JL There was no data set here, there is no points on the graph of my answer. I left indices.txt and points.txt here for the example ;)