# Rotating curve by 360 degrees properly with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing about the volume by an integral, and I had to draw this.

[image]

How do I draw it properly?

Here is my codes:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=1.7cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (25,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,1.93) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,-1.93) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (4,-1.93) .. controls (3.3,0) .. (4,1.93) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (4,-1.93) .. controls (4.7,0) .. (4,1.93) ;

\draw[sloped] (5,0) .. controls (6.19,1.86) and (7.74,1.12) .. (8.2,1.83) ;
\draw[sloped,dashed] (5,0) .. controls (6.19,-1.86) and (7.74,-1.12) .. (8.2,-1.83) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (8.2,-1.83) .. controls (8.7,0) .. (8.2,1.83) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (8.2,-1.83) .. controls (7.7,0) .. (8.2,1.83) ;

\draw[sloped] (9,0) .. controls (11.04,1.96) .. (14.59,0) ;
\draw[sloped,dashed] (9,0) .. controls (11.04,-1.96) .. (14.59,0) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (11.04,-1.5) .. controls (10.5,0) .. (11.04,1.5) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (11.04,-1.5) .. controls (11.5,0) .. (11.04,1.5) ;

\draw (15.79,0) -- (17.5,1.93) -- (22,0) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (15.79,0) -- (17.5,-1.93) -- (22,0) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (17.5,-1.93) .. controls (16.8,0) .. (17.5,1.93) ;
\draw[dashed,sloped] (17.5,-1.93) .. controls (18.1,0) .. (17.5,1.93) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using an `ellipse`:

[image]

### References:

- [Symbol for "rotate around axis"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36534/symbol-for-rotate-around-axis/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=1.7cm]{geometry}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36534/symbol-for-rotate-around-axis/
\newcommand{\AxisRotator}[1][rotate=0]{%
    \tikz [x=0.25cm,y=0.60cm,line width=.2ex,-stealth,#1] \draw (0,0) arc (-150:150:1 and 1);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]

\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (25,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw (-2,0)  -- (0.25,0) node [midway] {\AxisRotator[rotate=-180]};

\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,1.93) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,-1.93) -- cycle;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (4,-1.93) .. controls (3.3,0) .. (4,1.93) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (4,-1.93) .. controls (4.7,0) .. (4,1.93) ;
\draw [blue, thick] (4,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5cm, y radius=1.92cm];

\draw[sloped] (5,0) .. controls (6.19,1.86) and (7.74,1.12) .. (8.2,1.83) ;
\draw[sloped,dashed] (5,0) .. controls (6.19,-1.86) and (7.74,-1.12) .. (8.2,-1.83) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (8.2,-1.83) .. controls (8.7,0) .. (8.2,1.83) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (8.2,-1.83) .. controls (7.7,0) .. (8.2,1.83) ;
\draw [blue, thick] (8.2,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5cm, y radius=1.80cm];

\draw[sloped] (9,0) .. controls (11.04,1.96) .. (14.59,0) ;
\draw[sloped,dashed] (9,0) .. controls (11.04,-1.96) .. (14.59,0) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (11.04,-1.5) .. controls (10.5,0) .. (11.04,1.5) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (11.04,-1.5) .. controls (11.5,0) .. (11.04,1.5) ;
\draw [blue, thick] (11.04,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5cm, y radius=1.47cm];

\draw (15.79,0) -- (17.5,1.93) -- (22,0) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (15.79,0) -- (17.5,-1.93) -- (22,0) -- cycle;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (17.5,-1.93) .. controls (16.8,0) .. (17.5,1.93) ;
%\draw[dashed,sloped] (17.5,-1.93) .. controls (18.1,0) .. (17.5,1.93) ;
\draw [blue, thick] (17.5,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5cm, y radius=1.88cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

### Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\def\f{(sin(x)+1.2)}
\pstVerb{/I2P {AlgParser cvx exec} def}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {10,...,25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-3)(7,3)
    \psVolume[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange!50,linecolor=blue](0,\psPiTwo){\n}{\f I2P}
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-2.75)(6.75,2.75)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does this doesn't paint “correctly” all of the small cylinders? I mean, in the (approximated) interval [1.5,4.5] —where the derivative is negative— all the cylinders are missing one line (they should look exacty like the last cylinder —with *that* edge visible—). I know nothing about `pstricks` so may be you are telling it not to do so.

Comment: @Manuel: Please illustrate your question with some screenshots so I can easily grasp what you meant.

Comment: It's just the 3D of the cylinders, that in the interval I pointed evey cylinder is missing one edge (the one shown in the last cylinder to the right). In the rest of cylinders (out of that interval) that edge doesn't matter because the cylinder next to it is bigger and hides it.

Comment: @Manuel: I think it is a bug. :-)

Comment: Ok. I was trying to explain better, but I see you understood me ;)