# Recreation of Rotational Arrow in 3-D Space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, 3d

What would be the best way to recreate an arrow like this in 3d that represents a rotation?[image]

Comment: Maybe this solution is something for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665080/47927

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, smooth]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sa}{-65}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ea}{245}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rx}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ry}{0.4}
\draw[fill=blue!20] plot[domain=\sa:\ea] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{\ry*sin(\x)}) -- ++(0,-\ry) --  plot[domain=\ea:\sa] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{-\ry+\ry*sin(\x)}) --cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!80] plot[domain=180:\ea] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{\ry*sin(\x)}) -- ++(0,0.5*\ry) -- ++(\ry,-\ry) -- ++(-\ry,-\ry) -- plot[domain=\ea:180] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{-\ry+\ry*sin(\x)}) -- ++(0,\ry) --cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!80] plot[domain=\sa:0] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{\ry*sin(\x)}) -- ++(0,-\ry) -- plot[domain=0:\sa] ({\rx*cos(\x)},{-\ry+\ry*sin(\x)}) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D round arrow]