# how to put graph in the paragraph with text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to put some special symbols as highlighted in the following picture in to the text garagraph, I just know how to put graph independent from the paragraph. Would someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Are these symbols `tikzpictures`, since you added the `tikz-pgf` tag? If so, you can add the `tikzpicture` environment or `\tikz` command in a `\newcommand` such as this: [Quartertone symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/31842#31842)  If they are images, just add `\includegraphics` in the text, or wrap that in a newcommand as well.

Comment: Another related/duplicate: [How to add a custom symbol to LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13594)