# How to add musical symbols like flats and sharps in text

Tags: symbols, music

I need a to use musical symbols, flats, sharps and such in my thesis. This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

I use ShareLaTeX, the online LaTeX thing.

Comment: `$\flat$ $\sharp$ $\natural$`

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/quartertone-symbols

Comment: Related: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)