# How do I include the musical symbol for half-flat?

Tags: fonts, symbols, music

I cannot find the musical symbol for semi-flat. This is a reversed flat symbol. Where can I find this symbol?

Comment: Welcome. // You can find it here: https://www.google.com/search?q=semi-flat+symbol . // Sorry, that's the kind of answers you'll get here at best with little to no specifics. It's always a good idea to include relevant code in your question.

Comment: Also, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16712/47927

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `lilyglyphs` package that gives you access to the Emmentaler font that contains a huge range of musical symbols. Not every symbol has a shorthand command defined by the package, but you can access all glyphs using the `\lilyGlyph` command. Check the list of available glyphs and their names in the [online Lilypond documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/the-emmentaler-font). For this to work, you need to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, lilyglyphs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ p{2em} l }
        \flat &
            \verb|\flat| \\
        \lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.flat} &
            \verb|\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.flat}| \\
        \flatflat &
            \verb|\flatflat| \\         
        \lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.flatflat} &
            \verb|\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.flatflat}| \\
        \lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.mirroredflat} &
            \verb|\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.mirroredflat}| \\
        \lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.mirroredflat.flat} &
            \verb|\lilyGlyph[scale=1.5]{accidentals.mirroredflat.flat}| \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be either my eyes or the browser I'm using (FireFox), but the `scale=1.5` doesn't seem to be taking effect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do see a difference: Without `scale=1.5`, I get smaller glyphs.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'm willing to believe my laptop is playing tricks on me -- it is known to be sick in other respects.  But changing the scale factor to something much larger definitely works.  Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own using `\reflectbox` from the `graphicx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\semiflat}{\reflectbox{$\flat$}}

\begin{document}

$\flat\semiflat\flat$

\end{document}
```

An alternate notation has a flat sign with a slash:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\semiflat}{\reflectbox{$\flat$}}
\newcommand{\varsemiflat}{\raisebox{.9ex}{\rotatebox{45}{\rule{1ex}{.25pt}}}\hspace{-.22em}\flat}

\begin{document}

$\flat\varsemiflat\flat$

\end{document}
```